# Randomly distributing numbers from multiple arrays

Tags: objective-c

So I'm trying to simulate a card game mid hand.  Each player has a "guess array" that contains all the possible cards the other players might have.  These arrays are based on the play history of the other players.  If a player is not able to follow suit, the AI removes all the cards of the lead suit from that player's guess array.  For instance, if Spades are lead and the second players puts down a heart, the code will remove all cards in the Spade suit from player 2.

The problem I'm running into is the following case:

```
OL  P   OR
1   1   1
    2   2
3   3
```

Here, OL (Opponent Left) can have cards 1 and 3.  P (Partner) can have cards 1,2, and 3. Finally, OR (Opponent Right) can have cards 1 and 2.

Right now the code isn't smart to handle the situation where OL chooses Card 1 and the Parner chooses Card 2.  This results in the opponent right array in being totally empty resulting in a fatal error.

I attempted to get around this by distributing the cards in a while loop.  As long as any of the arrays are less than full, the loop will continue to randomly distribute cards.  My issue with this method is that it could lead to an apparent infinite loop, or at the very least significantly reduce game play speed.

```
while (guessplayerOLfull==false || guessplayerPfull==false || guessplayerORfull==false)
{
    numplayerleft= 0;
    numpartner= 0;
    numplayerright= 0;

    [guessplayerOLremaining removeAllObjects];
    [guessplayerPremaining removeAllObjects];
    [guessplayerORremaining removeAllObjects];

    [guessplayerOL removeAllObjects];
    [guessplayerP removeAllObjects];
    [guessplayerOr removeAllObjects];

    [guessplayerOLremaining addObjectsFromArray:opplefthand];
    [guessplayerPremaining addObjectsFromArray:partnerhand];
    [guessplayerORremaining addObjectsFromArray:opprighthand];

    for (int m=0; m<[opplefthand count]-1; ++m)
    {
        if (![opprighthand containsObject:opplefthand[m]] && ![partnerhand containsObject:opplefthand[m]] )
        {
            numplayerleft=numplayerleft+1;
            [guessplayerOL addObject:opplefthand[m]];
            [guessplayerOLremaining removeObject:opplefthand[m]];
        }
    }

    for (int m=0; m<[partnerhand count]-1; ++m)
    {
        if (![opprighthand containsObject:partnerhand[m]] && ![opplefthand containsObject:partnerhand[m]] )
        {
            numpartner=numpartner+1;
            [guessplayerP addObject:partnerhand[m]];
            [guessplayerPremaining removeObject:partnerhand[m]];
        }
    }

    for (int m=0; m<[opprighthand count]-1; ++m)
    {
        if (![opplefthand containsObject:opprighthand[m]] && ![partnerhand containsObject:opprighthand[m]] )
        {
            numplayerright=numplayerright+1;
            [guessplayerOR addObject:opprighthand[m]];
            [guessplayerORremaining removeObject:opprighthand[m]];
        }
    }

    //Fill Player Left Array
    for (int n=0; n<[playerhand count] -1 -numplayerleft; n++)
    {
        if ([guessplayerOLremaining count]>1)
        {
            player_left_random =(arc4random() % ([guessplayerOLremaining count]-1));

            [guessplayerOL addObject:guessplayerOLremaining[player_left_random]];
            [guessplayerORremaining removeObject:guessplayerOLremaining[player_left_random]];
            [guessplayerPremaining removeObject:guessplayerOLremaining[player_left_random]];
            [guessplayerOLremaining removeObject:guessplayerOLremaining[player_left_random]];
        }
        else
        {
            player_left_random=0;
        }
    }

    for (int m=0; m<[guessplayerPremaining count]; ++m)
    {
        if (![opprighthand containsObject:guessplayerPremaining[m]] )
        {
            numpartner=numpartner+1;
            [guessplayerP addObject:guessplayerPremaining[m]];
            [guessplayerPremaining removeObject:guessplayerPremaining[m]];
        }
    }

    //Fill Partner Array
    for (int n=0; n<[playerhand count]-1 -numpartner; n++)
    {
        if ([guessplayerPremaining count]>1)
        {
            player_left_random =(arc4random() % ([guessplayerPremaining count]-1));

            [guessplayerP addObject:guessplayerPremaining[player_left_random]];
            [guessplayerOLremaining removeObject:guessplayerPremaining[player_left_random]];
            [guessplayerORremaining removeObject:guessplayerPremaining[player_left_random]];
            [guessplayerPremaining removeObject:guessplayerPremaining[player_left_random]];
        }
        else
        {
            player_left_random=0;
        }
    }

    [guessplayerOR addObjectsFromArray:guessplayerORremaining];

    if ([guessplayerOL count]==[playerhand count]-1)
    {
        guessplayerOLfull=true;
    }

    if ([guessplayerP count]==[playerhand count]-1)
    {
        guessplayerPfull=true;
    }

    if ([guessplayerOR count]==[playerhand count]-1)
    {
        guessplayerORfull=true;
    }

} //End While
```

It seems to me that there should be some method to determine that Partner must pick Card 3 if Opponent Left picked Card 1.  What am I missing here?  Seems like this should be obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a four player game...

If every player has at least four choices left, then there are no restrictions on the first card played. You can choose randomly, remove the card from the other hands, choose again and so on.

The problem arises when some players have fewer than four choices. In particular, if three players have the same three choices, then those choices are not available for the fourth player. Likewise, if two players have the same two choices, then those choices are not available to the other two players. And if one player has only one choice, then that choice is not available to the other three.

---

So given this situation

```
OL  P   OR
1   1   1
    2   2
3   3
```

if OL chooses card 1, then you're left with

```
P  OR
2  2
3
```

Now you have a player (OR) with only one choice (2). Therefore, 2 is not an option for P.

---

As another example, consider this situation

```
OL  P   OR
1   1   1
2   2   2
3
```

In this case, two players (P and OR) have the same two choices (1 and 2). Therefore, 1 and 2 are not an option for OL. So, in fact the situation is really

```
OL  P   OR
3   1   1
    2   2
```

---

Extending this to four players makes things more interesting. Consider

```
ME  OL  P  OR
1   1   1  1
2   2   2  2
3   3
4
```

Two players (P and OR) have the same two choices (1 and 2), so this reduces to

```
ME  OL  P  OR
3   3   1  1
4       2  2
```

But now one player (OL) has one choice (3), so reduce again to

```
ME  OL  P  OR
4   3   1  1
        2  2
```

and those are the actual choices.

---

In general,

- apply the rules iteratively until no reductions are possible
- choose a card for a player
- remove that card from the other player's lists
- repeat until all the cards are chosen

Comment: Iteratively is exactly what I need to be doing.  I need to rearrange the dealing process a bit and check to see if there is only one card left for any player to choose from instead of simply randomizing it.  Thank you for such a lengthy, well thought out response!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain a set of possible cards for every player, the overall algorithm would be something like:

1. Add the entire deck of cards to every player's set
2. Remove your own hand from every other player's set
3. When a player plays a card:

   - remove the card played from every other player's set
   - for every card in the set of the player who played the card, remove it if the rules of the game imply that they can't have it given the card they just played
4. Whenever a player's set has only one card remaining, it is the only card they could possibly have - it is now a known fact that they have it, and the card can be removed from other players' sets (which may then also end up with only one card remaining)

It is important to not "guess" or speculate when following these steps, i.e., a card may only be removed from a set in step 3 if it is actually played, or if it would be *impossible* according to the rules of the game that the player has that card. Do *not* remove cards from these sets based on probabilities, only 100% fact (see below for incorporating guesses if needed).

Note that since these are sets, you can use `NSMutableSet` for higher performance, and it includes handy methods like `minusSet:`.

The resulting sets will contain all possible cards that every player may have in a deterministic manner (assuming that the software prevents breaking the rules of the game). If you wish to have additional, smaller sets that are "guesses" of what they might have, you could construct them separately and use `interesectSet:` on them whenever the set of all possible cards is updated.

For instance, the guess set could also remove cards that the player would be stupid to not have played instead of the one they played, but this guess can be wrong (since players can be stupid), so you cannot depend on the guess set being correct or non-empty (fall back to the set of all possible cards if it is).

If you find yourself in the situation you describe in the question, the empty set of guessed cards means you've guessed wrong! So check for the guessed set being empty – if not, use it, if yes, recover by copying that player's set of all possible cards to the guessed set. That's why you must have the factual set of all possibilities, not just the guesses.

You must maintain both the guessed set and set of all possible cards in parallel at all times according to rule 3 above. This includes any simulated games you run; you must update the sets used in the simulation just as though the simulated moves were real. Since you don't want to lose track of your actual sets, you'll need to create a new copy of them for each round of simulation.

Comment: That's more or less what the code is already doing except I'm using mutable arrays. I'm hoping to run some Monte Carlo simulations where it deals the guess arrays into the simulated player arrays...and does this for every possible card the current player could put down.  The problem is I'm trying to deal the cards with constraints and the current dealing mechanism is failing miserably.

Comment: @PWiggin In a Monte Carlo simulation you'd simulate the game as though it were actually happening, i.e., pick a card from the set of possible cards (created as described in the answer) and – the important step – then also run the steps to remove it from the players' sets of possibilities as described in the answer. You'll have to create duplicates of the sets for _every round_ of the simulation so you don't lose the original sets (for the real game and starting point of next simulation). This is where you'll need the sets for performance.

Comment: @PWiggin Also note that for this to work you must create the set of _all_ possible cards each player could have. Based on your question you are indeed doing only “more or less” that, because if you were doing exactly that, no set could be prematurely empty. So if you make these “guessed” sets and find it is empty, you've guessed wrong and need to fall back on the set of all possibilities (which can never be empty unless the game is over and the player can have no cards).

Comment: Yes, i am simulating the game and I have the original arrays stored outside the loop.  There are really three sets of arrays.  (I.e. oppleft , playerOL, and playerOLremaining).  For each iteration in the MC sim, playerOLremaining will contain all the cards from oppleft.  As the cards randomly chosen, they'll be added to the playerOL array and removed from the player__remaining arrays.   User's answer above describes in much better detail the issue I'm having than my OP.  The large guess arrays are never empty.   It's when you start actually dealing the cards out that the code breaks down.

Comment: @PWiggin Well, the issue described in your question is that the the "OR" array did become empty, and it was not a set of all possible cards since clearly card 3 was possible for them to have and yet it was not initially in the array. Also in this comment you mention _adding_ cards to an array; the correct approach is to never add cards, but to begin with all cards and only remove them when it is 100% impossible for that player to have the card (i.e., played by other player or prevented by rules of the game based on what they played or because another player must have it).

Comment: @PWiggin That is basically just to say that the algorithm I describe here _will_ work if, but only if, you follow it to the letter (which includes never adding cards to the sets of possible cards, only removing). But if you found another answer to solve the issue in a different way, that's also good, hope it works out. =)

Comment: Thanks for the help Arkku.  I'm sure it would make sense if you saw the whole code.